# Trouble with simple password program -- Java

Tags: java

I was doing some programming one night and I ran into a problem. It seems the if statement in the action listener for my button is not being picked up. I am farely new to programming so I hope it is not anything too obvious Any suggestions? Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JTextField tfUsername, tfPassword;
JLabel jlUser, jlPass;
JTextArea tarea;
JButton bLogin;

public Login(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login Test");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    jlUser = new JLabel("Username");
    tfUsername = new JTextField(20);
    jlPass = new JLabel("Password");
    tfPassword = new JTextField(20);
    bLogin = new JButton("Login");
    tarea = new JTextArea();

    frame.setSize(335,150);
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(jlUser);
    panel.add(tfUsername);
    panel.add(jlPass);
    panel.add(tfPassword);
    panel.add(bLogin);
    panel.add(tarea);
    bLogin.addActionListener(this);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
new Login();

}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(e.getSource() == bLogin){
        String user = tfUsername.getText();
        String pass = tfPassword.getText();
        String be = "hi";

                    if(pass == be){
            tarea.setText("Successful");
        }
}

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is with how you are comparing the `pass` and `be` `String`s

```
if (pass == be) {
    tarea.setText("Successful");
}
```

This is comparing the Object references, not their content, which will always be false...Instead you should be using `.equals`

```
if (pass.equals(be)) {
    tarea.setText("Successful");
}
```

This will do a case sensitive comparison.  If required, you can also use `.equalsIgnoreCase` where the case does not matter

For passwords, you should be using `JPasswordField` and storing the password in a `char` array, as `String` values are easier to pick out of memory.

This would then require you to use [`Arrays.equals(char\[\], char\[\])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28char%5B%5D,%20char%5B%5D%29) instead

See [How to use Password Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) for more details...

Answer (score 1):

So far what i can see is the String compare error. Post the error log to see if there is any other error.
In the string match try

```
if (pass.equals(be)) {
    tarea.setText("Successful");
}
```

You can also use compareto function as well to check String

Also gettext for pass is not very secured

Comment: u are faster, congrats

Comment: Sorry, it's early and I've had little sleep, so I'm a little cynical. I'm certainly not against people expanding on answers or providing additional points of view, but it does get annoying when people populate the questions with the same answer - IMHO :P

Comment: Apologies, I'm having a rant, and you just got in the way :P